# Required executor memory is above the max threshold of this cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am running Spark on an 8 node cluster with yarn as a resource manager. I have 64GB memory per node, and I set the executor memory to 25GB, but I get the error:
`Required executor memory (25600MB) is above the max threshold (16500 MB) of this cluster! Please check the values of 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.`
I the set `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` to 25600 but nothing changes.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Executor memory is only the heap portion of the memory.  You still have to run a JVM plus allocate the non-heap portion of memory inside a container and have that fit in YARN. Refer to the image from [How-to: Tune Your Apache Spark Jobs (Part 2)](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) by Sandy Ryza.
[image]

If you want to use executor memory set at 25GB, I suggest you bump up `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` to something higher like 42GB.

Comment: I tried that, but the error indicates that my threshold is still at 16500 MB!

Comment: And you restarted YARN?  Can you provide a screenshot of the YARN UI that shows total capacity (vcores, memory)?

Comment: Yes I did restart yarn, please check my initial post, I added a screenshot.

Comment: You're using capacity scheduler.  See if you've set `yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.maximum-allocation-mb` to the lower value.

Comment: What do you mean by the lower value? Anyway, I set `yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.maximum-allocation-mb` to 24000 and then to 16500 but unfortunately, it didn't work. Of course, I kept  `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` at 24000 as well because "This setting overrides the cluster configuration yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb"

Comment: What I meant was looking at your YARN UI output, you have almost 40GB of memory per node.  So if you're still hitting that resource limit, maybe you've created an artificial ceiling of memory through your scheduler policy.  And 24000 is still too low.  Try 43000 (~42GB) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't solve it. I remember that the threshold seen in the error message (16500) was a number I set when I was using Hadoop with HDFS (now I use another filesystem instead) and it was set for the property `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`. Now, even though I change it, the threshold is still the same!

Comment: But when you change your YARN settings do you see differences in the YARN UI indicating the new values?  Another thing to try is `grep 16500` all your *-site.xml files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195526/discussion-between-user9332151-and-tk421).

Comment: Driver executor container runs on only one of the NodeManager group. You need to set yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb, for NodeManager group, which is greater than (Required driver executor memory+overhead).